# Tag Merge Request: fem & finite element

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I think we should merge the [fem](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fem) tag into the [finite-element](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-element).  Any objections?

Comment: nope, just do it!